# Mocking REST calls in Svelte

Tags: rest, unit-testing, svelte

Hi I've been using Svelte for some weeks not and really enjoy it.
I was trying to set up unit tests according to https://testing-library.com/docs/svelte-testing-library/intro/
and that went also well. What that guide does not include however, is how I should mock my REST calls. I have tried following without success:
jest-mock-fetch
jest-fetch-mock
jest-mock-promise
msw server (this does not respond anything, maybe it works only for React applications?)

Has anyone successfully mocked the REST calls in a Svelte app, if so could you post a minimal fiddle to show me what libs to use and how it looks like. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mocking the request functions you can mock at the network layer with the [msw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msw) library. This has the added benefit of not being tied to fetch, so you could replace with axios if need be.

It would look something like this:

```js
import {rest} from 'msw'
import {setupServer} from 'msw/node'

const server = setupServer(
  rest.get('/my-api', (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.json({greeting: 'hello there'}))
  }),
)

beforeAll(() => server.listen())
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers())
afterAll(() => server.close())


test('does what I want it to', async () => {
  // the actual test...
})
```

You can have a look at the [react examples](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro/#full-example) in the testing library. Although it's specifically for react, the `msw` use can be used the same in svelte testing.

Comment: Yes, msw seems to be the best solution. However, for some reason my calls do not reach the rest.get stub. Have you successfully been using msw with Svelte?

Comment: yes, with axios. Haven't tried with fetch